# Updating install script for OpenVino 2023.0.0 version

Tags: openvino

I am trying to update the openvino version from 2021 version to the latest 2023.0.0 in the WasmEdge repository but i am getting this error "line 19: /opt/intel/openvino_2023/bin/setupvars.sh: No such file or directory" . Any suggestions How I can fix this.
https://github.com/WasmEdge/WasmEdge/pull/2636
I have also linked the PR from github.

I was expecting the script to run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from OpenVINO version 2022.1.0 onwards the *setupvars.sh* script is under a different location:

```
/opt/intel/openvino_2023.0.0/setupvars.sh
```

Try updating the path in your application to point to the new script location.

For this and more information on OpenVINO 2023.0 version, kindly refer to https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.0/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_from_archive_linux.html#step-1-download-and-install-the-openvino-core-components

Comment: Actually I mixed up the installation via archive method and apt method. So we don't require to mention the `/opt/intel/openvino_2023.0.0/setupvars.sh` .